# Conflict with upload_tmp_dir and open_basedir

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx, open-basedir

I have a web server (Debian, Nginx) with multiple sites written in PHP. For security reasons, I'm restricting each site with `open_basedir` by specifying it as `fastcgi_param` in the Nginx configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "open_basedir=$document_root";
}
```

This does however complicate file uploads from frontend, as the default temporary directory (`upload_tmp_dir`) is outside the `open_basedir`. The optimal solution would be to add it as another `fastcgi_param`:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_tmp_dir=$document_root/wp-content/tmp";
```

This doesn't work, though, as it seems like `upload_tmp_dir` must be set in php.ini - which wouldn't work with my multiple sites.

How can I solve this and still maintain the `open_basedir`?

Comment: What about making each site upload path inside a main tmp path? Or keep them all at the same tmp place but use some unique value for each site for creating tmp files.

Comment: But if `open_basedir` is `/var/www/site1` and `/var/www/site2`, how should they share `upload_tmp_dir`? :-)

Comment: No idea how, was just a translucent thought :) what about a symlink? hmm this should also be possible: php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/html/:/usr/local/php/tmp/ where tmp is then shared across sites.